# Is this vector inside the box formed by 3 other vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have this question:
Is $\begin{pmatrix} 4 \cr 1\cr 2  \end{pmatrix}$ inside the box formed by $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \cr 3\cr 1  \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 \cr 6\cr 1  \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0\cr 5  \end{pmatrix}$?

My attempt:

$$a\begin{pmatrix} 3 \cr 3\cr 1  \end{pmatrix}+ b\begin{pmatrix} 2 \cr 6\cr 1  \end{pmatrix} +c\begin{pmatrix} 1 \cr 0\cr 5  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \cr 1\cr 2   \end{pmatrix}$$

where $a = \frac{99}{51}, b = \frac{-40}{57}$, and $c = \frac{11}{57}$. This is where I am stuck. I think I have found the scale factors for each vector of the box, but how do I know if the plane formed by $\begin{pmatrix} 4 \cr 1\cr 2  \end{pmatrix}$ is in the box?

Thank you!

Comment: What means "the box"? Cause those vectors are linearly independent, so they generate the whole space.

Comment: I assume they mean the parallelipiped corresponding to the three, so I would guess it has to be a convex linear combination of the three. (Or something like it, where the coefficients can be in $[0,1]$ inclusive, but not outside.)

Comment: Yes exactly, the 3D parallelepiped formed by the intersection of the 3 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parallelepiped.html) at its word (since I was somewhat uncertain, but finding it made me feel a lot better):

A vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is in the parallelipiped made by $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ if there are $a,b,c \in [0,1]$ such that

$$v = ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3$$

At present, that should suggest your vector is not in the parallelipiped (since $a,b \not \in [0,1]$) -- **but** this is a nonissue since your process of deriving the constants was in error (as [WolframAlpha confirms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=99%2F51+*+%283%2C3%2C1%29+%2B+%28-40%2F57%29+*+%282%2C6%2C1%29+%2B+11%2F57+*+%281%2C0%2C5%29)).

After solving it myself, it seems your $a$ should be $99/57=33/19$, not $99/51$. Correcting that [fixes everything](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=99%2F57+*+%283%2C3%2C1%29+%2B+%28-40%2F57%29+*+%282%2C6%2C1%29+%2B+11%2F57+*+%281%2C0%2C5%29), and still confirms the result: your vector is not in the parallelipiped.

---

**In short:** the key issue is whether your coefficients are in $[0,1]$. Since not all of them are, then you're not in the parallelipiped.

Comment: thank you! But I don't understand where the  $a,b,c \in [0,1]$ comes from, i.e., why do the coefficients have to be within those numbers, and is that something specific to parallelepiped? Secondly, would another but less elegant way of solving be to find the det. (i.e., volumn) of the box, then just estimate to see if the 3-tuple exceeds the volumn. Thanks!

Comment: It's not just about parallelipipeds, but these "boxes" in general (in however many dimensions you want). Essentially, getting a negative coefficient is going to "flip" the vector outside of the box. That is, $ax$ points vaguely in the direction of $x$ for $a>0$, but vaguely away for $a<0$. [I made a Desmos demo that might help to visualize things if you play with it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mifqv8vv13).

Comment: As for your other comment, a single $3$-tuple is not associated with a volume, so I'm not sure what you're trying to get at.